# Critical Error #-2147217887 Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: vb6, upsizing

I've converted an access DB to an SQL express DB using the built in upsizing wizard in MS access. But I now get an error when I try to programmatically add a record to the SQL server table:

Critical Error #-2147217887  Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.

The field that this fails on is when I'm setting the SQL Field [notes]. I'm trying to set it to a vbnullstring (using VB6).

The access upsizing wizard created the field as a nvarchar(255) and all nulls to true, it originally  was a text field with a length of 255 in ms access.

Is there a problem setting a nvarchar field in sql to a vbnullstring?

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
Set RS = OpenRecordsetSQL("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AvailabilityBlocks WHERE BlockID=-1") 
' ' Add a specific entry to the Availability DB Table ' 
RS.AddNew 
RS("Begin") = wblock.BeginTime 
RS("Type") = wblock.BlockType 
RS("OCampus") = wblock.Campus
RS("End") = wblock.EndTime 
RS("LocationID") = wblock.LocationID 
RS("ResourceID") = wblock.ResourceID 
RS("RecurringSetNumber") = wblock.RWWSetNumber 
RS("Notes") = wblock.Notes 
RS("InternalNotes") = wblock.InternalNotes 
RS.Update
```

Comment: Set RS = OpenRecordsetSQL("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AvailabilityBlocks WHERE BlockID=-1")    '
    ' Add a specific entry to the Availability DB Table
    '
    RS.AddNew
    RS("Begin") = wblock.BeginTime
    RS("Type") = wblock.BlockType
    RS("OCampus") = wblock.Campus
    RS("End") = wblock.EndTime
    RS("LocationID") = wblock.LocationID
    RS("ResourceID") = wblock.ResourceID
    RS("RecurringSetNumber") = wblock.RWWSetNumber
    RS("Notes") = wblock.Notes
    RS("InternalNotes") = wblock.InternalNotes
    RS.Update

Comment: I added that to the post - impossible to read as a comment. Will "Notes" be null without it being set?

Comment: does  RS("Notes") = Null work?

Comment: I just set notes = NULL as you suggested instead of VBNullstring and that worked, well did not generate an error. Based on that results, is my above comment true that i cannot set an nvarchar field in SQL server to a "VBNULLSTRING"??? I find that impossible to believe!

Comment: I think vbNullString is a null pointer and 'Null' is the actual NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Null rather than vbNullString. vbNullString is a constant designed to be used when passing data to APIs. Null is the VB representation of a null value. NULL in the database sense.

One issue you have is that in VB a String cannot be Null. You can of course use VB's variant datatype so declare Notes as

```
Notes as Variant
```

Then either

```
wblock.Notes = "some text"
```

or

```
wblock = Null
```

Comment: Wow, so are you saying that i need to chase down everywhere in my code that uses vbnullstring and change it to an "" (empty string) if there is potential that the previous vbnullstring may be written out to the SQL server database?

Comment: You can use vbNullString just be careful if you save it to a field.